# How do I import shared modules using rollup without duplicating code?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs, ecmascript-next

I have two we components lets call then comp1 and comp2 and my project structure looks like this...

```
web-components
  packages
    comp1
      package.json
    comp2
      package.json
  lerna.json
  rollup.config.json
  package.json
```

Both of these import the Polymer material lib `@material/mwc-icon-button`. The problem arises when I build the projects. The material code is then injected into both outputs. I want to avoid this but I can't think of how to do it. I thought about using global variables but then the implementer has to know to install the material dependency and properly configure the global but this seems pretty onerous.

So the question is what is the proper way to do this without repeating code in the output?

Here is my full rollup config...

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import pug from 'rollup-plugin-pug';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

const globals = {}
// const external = Object.keys(pkg.dependencies);
const plugins = [
    resolve({
      module: true,
      main: true,
      jsnext:"main",
      browser: true
    }),
    postcss({
      plugins: []
    }),
    commonjs(),
    pug()
];
module.exports = {
  plugins,
  input: 'src/jrg-dropdown.mjs',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/index.mjs',
    format: 'esm',
    globals
  }
};
```

Comment: simply put the shared dependencies into third `vendors.js` file and depend first two outputs on it

Comment: lol why does it show a month old question as 'new'. broken site